# Is there a way to detect clicks in Google Sheets and run a function?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Spreadsheet as shown below.
[image]

The 30 at the bottom is what the title takes to display the points. How do I make it so that when the user clicks the buy button it will deduct the amount of points next to it (ignoring the text) from the 30 at the bottom and add a line below the 30 with it saying the item that was just purchased?

Eg.: User clicks the "Buy" Button on Item 1. Code takes the numbers only from the previous cell and deducts it from the 30 at the bottom of the sheet then creates a new row under the cell that was 30 and the new line's first cell displays the "Item".

Reference Image:
[image]

If anyone could help me with this that would be great.